# Can DataGridRow validation done for single element of row?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, validation

```
public static bool _isvalid = true ; 
public static void onhaschgd(DependencyObject obj,DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
     DataGridRow dgr = (DataGridRow)obj
     _isValid = (dgr !=null && Validation.GetHasError())?false:true
}
```

Basically my need is to validate only certain items of row, but the validation occurs as a whole row. Is there any way that I can select specific row item and do validation? Like `row.item['myfieldname']` something?

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate round the columns of each row and validate when you get to the one you want:

```
foreach (DataGridColumn col in DG1.Columns)
{
    col.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columns(v=vs.100).aspx